# Webhooks for Event start on Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Is there a way to get a webhook when an event starts or slightly before an event starts?

Google Calendar API allows to create reminders on events. Is it possible to get a webhook when an  event is activated or started?

For e.g., if I create an event for "Dec 15 2020 15:45 +0530", can I get a webhook at exactly that time, or a few minutes before?

Google may be using such a webhook to send out reminder emails or alarms. I want to use that to send notifications within my app.

Comment: @DaImTo Push Notifications are for changes to resources. What attribute of an event changes if it has started? I don't see any such attribute. Here's the doc I'm looking at: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events

Comment: The only ways I can think of:

1. Use a crafted email address, set an email reminder and watch for the emails to come in. But this may have latencies.
2. Poll the calendar say every 15minutes, and if the event is within the next 15 minutes wait/sleep until event start to send the notification. This would be precise, but also resource intensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*There is currently an open Feature Request on Google Issue Tracker to add an API for reminders for Calendar.*

What you can do in this situation is to star the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283) and eventually add a comment.

#### Workaround

You can create a script using Apps Script that will get all the events from a particular day and check their starting times.

```
function getEvents() {
    let today = new Date();
    let calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
    let events = calendar.getEventsForDay(today);
    let startTime = today.getHours();
    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        if (events[0].getStartTime() <= startTime) {
            // send email, notification etc;
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you can add an installable time-driven trigger which can run every 15 minutes for example to trigger the execution of the above function.

```
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getEvents')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(15)
      .create();
}
```

#### Note

Please bear in mind that you can customize the script and the trigger in such a way that it suits your needs accordingly.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script CalendarApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app);
- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: This looks very close to the solution I posted. Thanks for confirming that such an API does not exist. Accepting this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with IPaaS

With IFTTT's Google Calendar & Webhook applet,
IF=> Any Event Starts(You can set how many minutes/hours )
Then=> Post Webhooks

You can set its;

- title
- Description
- Location
- Start Time
- End Time
- EventURL
- VideoCallURl
  in additional headers, URL parameter and/or JSON body.

The timing of the trigger is not that accurate though.

Alternatively, you can use Integromat's Mailhook to work with the reminder notification.

1. Set forward setting in your gmail client for reminder notification to forward it to email address provided by Integromat
2. According to the contents of the email, make HTTP request to your endpoint.

You also have such services like;

https://mailhook.app/

for converting emails to webhooks.

https://cronhooks.io/

for creating a schedule to post webhooks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30593910)